# JS SocketIO singleton

Tags: javascript, sockets, ecmascript-6

i'm working with socket io, and would like to apply singleton pattern in order to keep the same instance of socket between different file

both main.js & device.js are loaded when on mobile, but have different socket instance

**Main.js :**

```
import ioInstance from './socket'    
console.log(ioInstance)
```

**Device.js :**

```
import ioInstance from './socket'
console.log(ioInstance)
```

**socket.js :**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
export const ioInstance = io('http://192.168.1.15:1337')
```

i've tried many ways of doing this but i always have different socket instance ...

Anyone having any clue on how to do it right ? Thanks

Comment: What is your execution environment?  Browser?  node.js?  Electron?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu, running this with express server and Chrome as browser

Comment: Is this code running in node.js with ubuntu or is this Chrome browser code?

Comment: This is the front end part of my small app

Comment: Indeed, i still can't see how to apply a singleton pattern to use the same instance in different file. Something else than just attaching my socket to my javacript window object

Comment: Hmmm, I'm reading that if you implement modules properly in a browser context and are running a recent enough browser version, then modules should only execute once, even if you import them more than once so your concept should work.  I guess we'd have to see a larger context for how your code works to see what you are doing differently or what is different about your execution environment from what I'm reading here: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/#modules-only-execute-once.

Comment: Here's the link the the singleton I've tried :https://github.com/hhochart29/Sockanvas/blob/socketSingleton/src/front/socket.js

Comment: So, apparently the actual code that has the problem is not as simple as the example you show in your question and that's why we're having trouble seeing the problem.   Your question should show the ACTUAL code.

Answer (score 5):

Your actual singleton code is not operating as a singleton at all.  When you have this:

```
const socketConnection = {
  _instance: null,
  get instance () {
    if (!this._instance) {
      this._instance = {
        setConnection () {
          return io('http://192.168.0.11:1337')
        },
      }
    }
    return this._instance
  }
}
```

And you are referencing:

```
socket.instance.setConnection()
```

That is calling `io('http://192.168.0.11:1337')` every time you reference `setConnection()`, even when `this._instance` is already set.  That's the problem.  Instead, you need to save or cache in the `instance` the result of calling `io('http://192.168.0.11:1337')` so you only ever call it once.

---

You could fix it by changing to this:

```
const socketConnection = {
  _instance: null,
  get instance () {
    if (!this._instance) {
      this._instance = io('http://192.168.0.11:1337');
    }
    return this._instance;
  }
}
```

And, then just using this to reference the singleton socket:

```
import socket from './socket'
console.log(socket.instance);
socket.instance.on(...);
```

---

You could also simplify matters and just have this:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socketConnection = io('http://192.168.0.11:1337');

export default socketConnection;
```

And, then just use this to reference the singleton socket:

```
import socket from './socket'
console.log(socket);
socket.on(...);
```

---

FYI, we probably would have solved this in minutes after posting your question if you showed the actual singleton code in your original question.  It's always better here to show your actual code than the try to make up a pseudo code example because the problem is often not exactly where you think so we need to see the real code to identify the actual solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I've tried exporting a simple const, but that's still creating 2 instances (You can check my github branch, updated according to your recommandation)

https://github.com/hhochart29/Sockanvas/tree/socketSingleton

Comment: @Hervé - Are you using webPack to bundle this for the client?  If so, have you looked at the actual generated code that runs in the browser to see what it is actually doing?

Comment: I am indeed using webpack. Will take a look as soon as I can

Comment: Per articles like this https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern, it should work if you're doing things properly.

Comment: Well the problem was coming from the fact that i was compiling 2 different file (bundle.js and device.js). i an now compiling into one single file and it is working. But i think that's not the good way cause it means my mobile device are loading the desktop js functions as well

Comment: @Hervé - That makes it sound like a bundling problem  - perhaps with how webPack or Babel are configured.

Comment: What i've done so far :
- splitted into 3 file when compiling (socket, main and device)
- used babel as transpilier
- made a simple export as you recommanded.

i tried to look at the code genereted by webpack but it's not meant to be read i guess. (everything is up to date on the socketSingleton branch)

Comment: Hello I tried two solutions because i had the same problem and i didnt know why i couldnt create a singleton. i use the solution with the Object{}.instance and its working but not the const one. I am using babel as transpiler and webpack as bundler that put every js in one file. I don't have the perfect answear but the check about the instance is important here like a global object ?